# C# Task is not a Task

Tags: c#, task

I am implementing an interface

```
Task Something()
```

but none of the code in the implementation is async

```
Task Something(){
    var x=1;
    return null;
}
```

This of course results in an error when called:

```
await Something()
```

How do I send back a blank Task to make the Interface happy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Task.FromResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to return a completed Task.

```
Task Something()
{
    var x=1;
    // Do *something* here ;)
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Note that this will run synchronously, and not be an asynchronous operation, so it'd be good to document that appropriately as well.

Answer (score 0):

If async is expected, why not make it async?

```
Task Something()
{
    return Task.Run( () => { /* your code here */ } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to await any method, it needs to have an async signature so in order to await Something() it should be made like:

```
async Task Something()
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Just remember that when you want to return a value you should return a Task and if you want to return void you should return only a Task

Comment: It does not need to be marked async to wait it - async is an implementation detail.  It only needs to return something, like Task, that is awaitable.